# Can you prove the area of a square is $x^2$ using areas of triangles?

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried this morning to prove that the area of a square whose side's length is $x$, is equal to $x^2$ using the areas of congruent triangles in the square. [image]
I thought that, as the number of triangles ($n$) increases, the sum of their areas get closer and closer to that of the square. Therefore, the square's area is the limit of the total areas of the triangles.

When doing the math, however, it didn't work out. Can anyone point out what's wrong here please?

Area of one triangle  $=0.5 \cdot \dfrac{x}{n} \cdot x$

Area of all triangles $ =0.5 \cdot \dfrac{x}{n} \cdot xn =  0.5x^2$

The limit(as n approaches infinity) of that is $0.5x^2$ not $x^2$

Why is that?

Comment: You only counted the black triangles which is half of  all the triangles.

Comment: I think a more pertinent question here is how do you know that the area of a triangle is $bh/2$?

Answer (score 1):

There are not n triangles, the number of triangles is 2n; thereby making the limit $$x^2$$

Comment: If you can call that a limit :) The limit is already reached for 2 triangles :)

Comment: Check out the picture, please.

Comment: Well yes, but he was asking about why the 'limit' was coming out wrong..

Comment: @Mahmoud Alawneh what about the picture, n black triangles and n white ones?

Comment: But if I used two triangles only, that wouldn't cover the whole area of the square (If I drew them like the problem suggests.)

Comment: Only the black ones.

Comment: @Mahmoud Alawneh why do you think only the black triangles cover the whole area of the square?, isn't the total area the sum of both black and white?

Comment: It's rtue that the the sum of both triangles gives the area of the square.

I actually want to prove the same result using a different approach. Look at the black triangles, The more we increase their number, the closer their total sum of areas gets to the area of the suare. That means the area of square is the limit of their total sum of areas. When I tried doing the math, it didn't work.

Comment: Think about this, if you say that the black triangles cover all the squares area, then some of the area is left every time (area of white triangles) when you increase the number of black triangles to infinite, note that there would also exist infinite white triangles which would give some fixed area. I hope this clears it....

Comment: @MahmouAlawneh No. Your equation above is correct and actually shows that (provided that there are an natural number of squares) the total area of the black squares is conserved as we add more squares. I can prove that there is always a nonzero area remaining no matter how many triangles you add by inscribing a rectangle of height $x/2$ and width $x/(2n)$ within each of the white triangles. Observe that the limit of the sum of these rectangles is $x^2/4 > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In a square where the diagonal makes up the two hypotenuses ofr two right angles triangles, the area for each triangle being $\frac{1}{2}bh$ where $b$ is the bas of the triangle and $h$ it's perpendicular height.

The sum of these two areas is clearly the area of the square, so
$$\text{Area of square} = \frac{1}{2} bh + \frac{1}{2}bh=bh$$
Since, for a square $b=h=x$ then the area is $x^{2}$.

Now generalise to further triangles.

Comment: Your method clearly works. I was trying to understand the concept of limits better by using it in a problem. Since my experiment works logically, it should also work mathematically, which it didn't.

Check out the picture to see what I mean, please.

Comment: I'm only using the black triangles.

Answer (score 0):

You have counted only the black triangles. The number of total triangles is not $n$, it is $2n$.

So, area of one triangle = $0.5 \cdot \dfrac{x}{n} \cdot x$
So, total area = $0.5 \cdot \dfrac{x}{n}\cdot x \cdot 2n = x^2$